# running executable files turn to be empty files when suddenly power off

Tags: c, linux, power-off

I have two executable files, whose source like below:

main_a.c

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    printf("start to copy\n");
    system("cp -pRf ~/main_b main_b");
    system("cp -pRf ~/main_a main_a");
    printf("done\n");
}
```

main_b.c

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    while (1) {
        printf("i'm b, i'm running\n");
    }
}
```

gcc -o main_a main_a.c
gcc -o main_b main_b.c

then I put **main_a** and **main_b** in **~** and **~/test**.

I cd in ~/test, running main_b in background like this

> ./main_b 1>/dev/null &

and run main_a in foreground link this

> ./main_a; sleep 100

wait a while, unplug the power, then reboot, i get two files whose size is zero and has no content in ~/test.

Anybody knows why?

PS:
to ensure file has been replaced, i touch ~/test/main_a and ~/test/main_b two hours ago and watch, then unplug the power.

> touch -d "2 hours ago" ~/test/*

Comment: whats was the file names which was created with size zero in the directory ~/test

Comment: What filesystem?  Do you run `fsck` after the power outage?

Comment: @Loong: Can you change your first program and instead of "-pRf" flag use "-pR". I think extra 'f' flag in cp command is causing forceful overwrite to these files with them-self and hence making it empty..

Comment: @tmp without a 'f' I cannot replacing the running main_b or main_a. My purpose is update them when they are running.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have run "fsck", but it shows nothing except "fsck from util-linux 2.20.1". Its filesystem is ext4.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the result code of each [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

And I would suggest calling [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) at the end of function `main` in `main_a.c`

Comment: Results of system(3) are fine. Calling sync(2) can solve the problem! But I still don't understand what happen before powering off.